# Rest API for Azure SSAS cube refreshment

Tags: c#, rest, azure, ssas, azure-analysis-services

I'm currently trying to create a Rest API to refresh a SSAS cube in Azure. I followed all the steps from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automating-azure-analysis-services-processing-with-azure-functions/). Then I'm using that code to refresh the Cube1 :

```
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DLL"
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.DLL"
#r "System.Configuration"

using System; 
using System.Security; 
using System.Security.Principal; 
using System.Configuration; 
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log) 
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function started at: DateTime.Now}");    
    // try  
    // {
    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server asSrv = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();

    log.Info("Log1");

    var connStr = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://serveraddress; Initial Catalog=Cube1;User ID=*****;Password=*****"; 
    log.Info("Log2");

    asSrv.Connect(connStr);        

    log.Info("Log3");   

    Database db = asSrv.Databases["Cube1"]; 
    log.Info("Log4");

    Model m = db.Model; 
    m.RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);     // Mark the model for refresh
    db.Model.SaveChanges();     //commit  which will execute the refresh
    asSrv.Disconnect();
    // }
    // catch (Exception e)
    // {
    //     log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function exception: {e.ToString()}");
    // }

    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function finished at: {DateTime.Now}"); 
}
```

Normally everything should be ok but here is my error message :

> Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****

Any idea to solve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which row throws the error?

Comment: asSrv.Connect(connStr);

I guess because the run machine displays the "log 2" and then an error

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are missing a reference to the nuget package [System.Security.Principal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal/)

```
#r "System.Security.Principal"
```

Comment: It's still the same error. Actually the error occurs after the log2

Comment: Are you deploying all the dependencies? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/install-distribute-and-reference-the-tabular-object-model

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is REST API available for Azure Analysis Services.

You can find it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh

To use it just

1. Create Azure AD Service Principal (Application)
2. Add it as admin to the server
3. Get token for this service principal for resource **https://*.asazure.windows.net**
4. Send POST request to

   https://**rollout**.asazure.windows.net/servers/**serverName**/models/**resource**/refresh

with body

```
{
  "Type": "Full",
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 2,
  "RetryCount": 2,
  "Objects": [
    {
        "table": "DimCustomer",
        "partition": "DimCustomer"
    },
    {
        "table": "DimDate"
    }
  ]
}
```

For detailed description check

https://marczak.io/posts/2019/06/logic-apps-refresh-analysis-services/